# JdbcTemplate: how to read large tables?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to dump database tables to a file using Spring jdbcTemplate. I can't use `pg_dump` or `psql` becase it's a custom data dump.

There are some large tables that causes `OutOfMemoryError`.

Theorically setting `fetchSize` to some number `> 0` would not eat up the memory as [stated](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#fetchsize-example).

I have tried:
`jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize()` and `rs.setFetchSize()`.

```
private void dumpTable(final String qry, final CSVPrinter csvPrinter) {
    jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(qry, (rs, rowNum) -> getObjects(rs)).forEach(objs -> {
        try {
            csvPrinter.printRecord(objs);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error", e);
        }
    });
}
```

Query looks  like this:

```
"select %s from %s t where exists(select 1 from log.log_table l where l.schema = '%s' and l.table = '%s' and l.key = t.%s and l.location in (0,%d))";
```

Also tried `jdbcTemplate.query()` with `RowCallbackHandler`.

Comment: use pagination by the sql query and recall it (depending on the row count)

Comment: This might get slow on large data, jdbc cursor would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue (on `application.properties`):

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```

I can confirm that it's needed for postgresql.